# How to find pet sitters in South-East asia?

Tags: pets

I want to know if pet sitting or other pet-frendly option to leave cat is available before entering the city.

So far I found two aggregators:

- https://www.petbacker.com/
- [www.trustedhousesitters.com](http://www.trustedhousesitters.com)

But there is not many options for example for Da nang (Vietnam), and second one is for free sitting, like on couch surfing, so I am not sure that this is reliable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several other "free" sitting sites (which are not at all free - people pay a fair amount of money just to be able to apply to sits, so do not take these as unreliable), as well, such as Nomador and MindMyHouse.

I am on several of these websites, and have done house sitting with animals many times (as a housesitter).  Aside from one abusive poster that should not have been on the site in the first place (long story), I've had good experiences across many sits.

I have no idea how common these sites are in SEA, or what the most popular there might be (I'm sure a quick internet search could answer this), but have found SEA to generally be much more conservative, so probably fewer exchange listings like this (far more common in Europe, and most of these sites are founded and based in Europe).

I hope you're able to find help in SEA.  Having lived there before, I know FB is generally more widely used for everything there, so maybe even posting in a local group would be a way to find a sitter...

Good luck!